# Maximum Number of BLE Advertising Packets Receivable per Second

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a quick question regarding BLE packets with iOS.

Say I have an iPhone app that sends out BLE advertising packets once a second in the background. This same app is also configured to receive advertising packets in the background. Say there are 30 other devices running this same app within Bluetooth range of the original device. Is there a theoretical maximum to the amount of packets any one device can receive within a given time interval? Could the app receive and process all the advertising packets from the thirty phones, or even 100 phones? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only receive one advertisement from a given device in the background; When your app is in the background it cannot opt-in to receiving duplicate advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on peripheral advertising speed/interval. If you have 20 ble device around ios device and start scan.
Then first get nearest device and which devices who advertising interval is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Well the BLE advertisements run at 1 MBit/s so that means one microsecond per bit.

In an advertisement packet the overhead is, on top of the advertisement data, the address of 6 bytes and then 10 bytes extra for BLE header and CRC.

If two packets are transmitted by two devices at the same time, they will interfere and possibly none of these packets can be detected at all.

With this information you should be able to calculate the rest of the Math yourself.